# consuming a Rest Wcf from Classic ASP

Tags: wcf, rest, asp-classic

Hi Need to post some data to a Rest Wcf Service.
With great difficulty I managed to get some help online.
But when I run my asp page I am getting the follwing error.
"Error: The processing of the WSDL parameter failed. Error: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter Error: Schema with target namespace -http://tempuri.org/- could not be found."
Any idea what mistake I am doing here.I really appreciate your help.
Here is my code for the asp page

---

```
<%
Dim wsdl, moniker, obj

wsdl = GetWsdlFromUrl("http://www.mysite.com/wcf/Service1.svc?wsdl")

moniker = "service:wsdl=" & wsdl & ", "
moniker = moniker + "http://www.mysite.com/wcf/Service1.svc,"
moniker = moniker + "contract=wcfservice1.IService1, "
moniker = moniker + "contractNamespace=http://tempuri.org/, "
moniker = moniker + "binding=webHttpBinding, "
moniker = moniker + "bindingNamespace=http://tempuri.org/"

Set objProxy = GetObject(moniker)

Dim str
str = objProxy.GetData()
`
Function GetWsdlFromUrl(strUrl)

Dim winHttpReq, resp

Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
resp = winHttpReq.Open("GET", strUrl, False)
winHttpReq.Send

GetWsdlFromUrl = winHttpReq.ResponseText

End Function 
%>
<html>
    Hello world:
</html>
```